# How can I remove items from carouFredSel within angular model?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamic, model, caroufredsel

I've encountered with some dillemma implementing carouFredSel for my dynamic carousel that is using angular model for the model-view-controller relationship.
Within angular I should delete items from my model scope but the problem is I also should worry about recalculating carousel size when items are deleting. And within carouFredSel I should delete items triggering custom event 'removeItem' on element on which I clicked however this event updates DOM tree but not model
Is there any way to correctly delete items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch your angular model and "re-initialize" carouFredSel on changes, like this:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', function factory($timeout) {
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.model = [...];
        $scope.deleteItem = function (item) {
            var index = $scope.model.indexOf(item);
            $scope.model.splice(index,1);
        };
    }],
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attributes) {       
        scope.$watch('model', function() {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.find('.foo').carouFredSel({
                    ...
                });
            }, 500);
        });
    }
}

<div class="foo">
    <div ng-repeat="item in model">
        <div ng-click="removeItem(item)">item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, if anybody will need at alternative solution here it is:
 $scope.imageStack.splice(index,1);
jQuery(window).resize();
For me it worked just fine ;)
I just give the plugin what it wants ;).